# npm install react-native-svg --save fails

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-native

Im new to react-native. I want to draw a chart , for that I came across [this](https://github.com/magicismight/react-native-svg) library. But unfortunately while installing the library from npm 
`npm install react-native-svg --save` I'm getting error.

```
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency react-native@^0.24.0 included from react-native-svg will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm ERR! Darwin 15.2.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "react-native-svg" "--save"
npm ERR! node v4.3.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package react-native@0.25.1 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-native-svg@1.2.6 wants react-native@^0.24.0

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/subodh/ReactNative/SVGDemo/npm-debug.log
```

Anybody out there can help regarding this ? 
Package.json contents :

```
{
"name": "SVGDemo",
"version": "0.0.1",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
 "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"
},
"dependencies": {
 "react": "^0.14.8",
 "react-native": "^0.25.1"
}
}
```

Comment: *"react-native-svg@1.2.6 wants react-native@^0.24.0"*. What does your package.json look like?

Comment: Please check the edits, also if I downgraded the version it wont hamper to any other code, right ? @ivarni